# Webcomic with roses and spirits

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I'm looking for a webcomic about a young girl in a steampunk-ish Victorian England world. The website itself is decorated in yellow. The comic is in color but there's a lot of pink and yellow, more so than other colors.

I think the main character or this weird best friend of hers is black? If I remember right. There's these spirit things and by chapter three (where I left off) the readers don't know if they're evil or not. The best friend seems to be connected to these spirits/magic somehow. There's adults, but they're not drawn in nearly as much detail as the kids. I remember the story seemed to focus a lot on roses but I didn't know why yet.

Comment: Could this be [Blindsprings](http://www.blindsprings.com/), by any chance?

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be **[Blindsprings](http://www.blindsprings.com/)**:

This is the main character, Tamaura Llyn ([of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tam_Lin))

[image]

Her friend, Street:

[image]

Here are the spirits, whose motives are (as of Chapter 3), dubious:

[image]

Here's her other friend, who is the one with the connection to the spirits. She is qualified to be a priestess to a bunch of snake spirits.

[image]